# Tables width wrong when create file with google driveService

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I am using c# and Google.Apis.Drive.V3 DriveService to create a document on google docs from HTML Razorview template. when I create the file to google docs the file is created successfully but with certain wrong format. I fixed almost all of this errors but there is one that is blowing my mind. I have tables that fit in entire document or HTML page, even when I specified the size of these tables in inches, cm or points anything works well. the tables have the wrong size when I upload the document and not cover 100% of the width. This is the picture that how the file is created:

[image]

Notice how even when I include a transparent pixel png on the first row, the table is smaller than I expected.

This is the code of the template that I am using for that:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        @@import url('https://themes.googleusercontent.com/fonts/css?kit=fpjTOVmNbO4Lz34iLyptLSsvxyIpIjyXbTpruCFAaFx6IoWp0s0DOH-yFNIUq8XG');
        @@page {
            size: 8.5in 11in;
            margin: 1.5cm;
        }
        table, td, tr, th {
            border: none;
        }

        .body-table {
            border-spacing: 0;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
            border: none;
            table-layout: fixed;
        }

        .v-align {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .h-center {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .p {
            padding-top: 0;
            padding-bottom: 0;
            line-height: 1.0;
            orphans: 2;
            widows: 2;
        }

        .prev-address {
            color: #505759;
            font-size: 9pt;
            text-align: right;
            width: 158.4pt;
        }
        .main-logo {
            width: 158.4pt;
        }
        .prev-title {
            font-size: 14pt;
            text-align: center;
            width: 230.4pt;
        }

        .width-30 {
            width: 30%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="min-width: 21.59cm; padding: 1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm">
    <table class="body-table" style="min-width: 19cm;">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><img style="width: 19cm" src="mypixel.png"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="width: 19cm;">
            <td class="main-logo width-30 v-align">Content 1</td>
            <td class="prev-title width-30 v-align h-center">Content 2</td>
            <td class="prev-address width-30">Content 3</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is how I am uploading with google drive service in c#:

```
var fileContent = await
    _viewRenderService.RenderToStringAsync("Quotes/PreviewTemplate", model);

var request = _driveService.Files.Create(new File
{
    CreatedTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
    MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.document",
    Name = $"{fileName}.html"
}, fileContent.ToStream(), "text/html; charset=utf-8");

await request.UploadAsync();
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong to get this weird behavior?

**UPDATE:**
I realized that this issue is related to the padding of the page, notice how in the image the padding/margins were configured to 0.5 cm. So, it seems that Google uses some kind of max-width for the content in that page but only affect to the tables or maybe set a max-width for tables uploaded with drive API and align the content to the left of the document.

Comment: importing HTML to a Google Doc is super-fragile. I would use the docs API instead.

Comment: In fact, I am creating the google document from HTML not uploading directly the HTML file.